# About Certificate chain endpoint sign shell command

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate

I have three certificate files (root.cer,middle.cer,endpoint.p12),they are a certificate chain.
How to sign a file use 'endpoint.p12' with shell command by openssl smime?

I use

`openssl smime -sign -in input.file -out output.file -signer endpoint.pem -inkey key.pem  -certfile root.pem -outform der -nodetach`

which root.pem is combined by middle and root .

But the result is not right. Any idea?

Comment: `openssl smime` (like all commandline operations other than `pkcs12`) can't use a pkcs12 file directly, but assuming your `endpoint.pem` is the result of 'importing' the pkcs12 to pem, and your `root.pem` contains 'middle' and 'root' certs both in PEM, that command should work and does for me (using my key&certs). In what way do you think 'the result is not right'?

Comment: You are right ,I export endpoint.pem and key.pem from endpoint.p12. The final file which post to  apple MDM server can not pass verification.So I think the result is wrong.

Comment: Okay, I don't know MDM, and the few existing Qs I see on it imply its error messages are vague and unhelpful but a likely cause is using a (or maybe some?) wrong cert(s). I suggest you check carefully what cert(s) you are using, and if you have or can get a good (working) example compare to that. Sorry I can't help further.